# Proving two sets are equal (Intersection of union of open balls)

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus

> Let $X$ be an arbitrary subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and, for each $\varepsilon > 0$, set $X_{\varepsilon } = \bigcup_{x\in X} B(x,\varepsilon )$. Prove that $\bigcap_{\varepsilon > 0} X_{\varepsilon }=cl(X).$

I can see intuitively why these two sets are equal, but not sure how to show it rigorously. I think I have to show that the LHS is contained in the RHS and vice versa. Any help?

Comment: Hint: $x\in cl(X)$ if and only if $B(x,r)\cap X\neq\emptyset$ for any $r>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your definition of closure.

Mine is $X' = \{ \text{limit points of }X\}$ the $\overline X = X' \cup X$.

So to prove $\cap_{\epsilon} X_\epsilon = \overline X$, have to prove

i) $\overline X \subset \cap_{\epsilon} X_\epsilon$.

Obviously, ever $x \in X$ is in every $B(x,\epsilon)$ and therefore in every $X_\epsilon$.

So we just need to prove that every limit point of $x$ is in each $X_\epsilon$.

This is s the standard "mutual neighbors" trick.  Is $e$ is a limit point and $\epsilon$ is an positive value then there is an $x\in X; x\ne e$ so $d(e,x) < \epsilon$.  But that means $e\in B_{x,\epsilon}$.  But keep in mind this is true for *all* epsilon so $e\in X_\epsilon $ for all $\epsilon$.  So $e\in \cap X_\epsilon$ and $X \subset \cap X_\epsilon$.

and

ii) $\cap_{\epsilon > 0}X_{\epsilon} \subset \overline X$

That is if $g$ *isn't* in $X$ and $g$ *isn't* a limit point then $g$ isn't in $\cap_{\epsilon > 0}X_{\epsilon}$.

Well, if $g$ *isn't* a limit point there is an $\epsilon > 0$ where $B(g,\epsilon)\cap X=\emptyset$.  Which means $g \not \in X_{\epsilon}$ so $g \not \in \cap X_{\epsilon}$.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

As is common in such proofs, you will need two parts.

**Part 1.**
Let $p \in cl(X)$. We would like to show that $\exists \varepsilon > 0$ and $x \in X$ such that $p \in B(x, \varepsilon)$. Can you finish this, using the fact that $p$ is in the closure of $X$?

**Part 2.**
Let $p \in \bigcap_{\varepsilon > 0} X_\varepsilon$. Can you show that $p$ must be in the closure of $X$?